# Why is this javascript array not returning true when tested?

Tags: javascript

UPDATE:

Running `typeof managers` reveals that it is an object.

When managers is tested for being an array, the test fails.  I am pushing all manager objects into this managers array if isManager property is true.

While the function is filtering the managers, and putting the objects into an array, the test returns that the array is NOT a valid array.

What am I missing here?  Brackets?  Does the status of the array change when I push objects into it?

CODE

```
userUtils.getManagers = function() {
  var managers = [];
  for (const manager of users) {
    if (manager.isManager === true) {
      managers.push(manager);
      let name = manager.name.first + ' ' + manager.name.last;
      console.log(name);
    }
    // console.log(managers);
  }
};
```

ERRORS

```
● Problem 2 - userUtils.getManagers() › userUtils.getManagers() should return a proper Array

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      12 |   test('userUtils.getManagers() should return a proper Array', function() {
      13 |     let managers = userUtils.getManagers();
    > 14 |     expect(Array.isArray(managers)).toBe(true);
         |                                     ^
      15 |     expect(managers.length).toBe(69);
      16 |   });
      17 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/problem-2.test.js:14:37)

  ● Problem 2 - userUtils.getManagers() › userUtils.getManagers() should only contain Manger users

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

      19 |     let managers = userUtils.getManagers();
      20 | 
    > 21 |     managers.forEach(manager => {
         |              ^
      22 |       // First, check the isManager property
      23 |       expect(typeof manager.isManager).toBe('boolean');
      24 |       expect(manager.isManager).toBe(true);

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/problem-2.test.js:21:14)
```

What the element looks like:

```
 * {
 *   "id": 1,                               // A unique Number
 *   "name": {                              // An Object with user names
 *     "first": "Paige",
 *     "last": "Bools"
 *   },
 *   "birthDate": "1995-02-04T07:34:45Z",   // A Date in String form
 *   "contact": {                           // An Object with contact info
 *     "phone": "8989068955",
 *     "email": "pbools0@webmd.com"
 *   },
 *   "address": {                           // An Object with address info
 *     "street": "476 Veith Parkway",
 *     "city": "Cuamba",
 *     "country": "Mozambique"
 *   },
 *   "accessCount": 776,                    // A Number: access count to the app
 *   "isManager": false                     // A Boolean: is this a manager?
 * }
 *
```

Comment: You don't return anything

Comment: Good eye.  I must be tired.

Answer (score 1):

`userUtils.getManagers` does not return anything. You need to add `return managers` at the end of the function; otherwise, if you do not return anything, it will implicitly result in an `undefined` return value, leading to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`.

```
userUtils.getManagers = function() {
  var managers = [];
  for (const manager of users) {
    if (manager.isManager === true) {
      managers.push(managers);
      let name = manager.name.first + ' ' + manager.name.last;
      console.log(name);
    }
    // console.log(managers);
  }
  return managers; //added return statement
};
```

Comment: Good catch.  I was getting wrapped around the axle.

Comment: @Daniel No problem.